# How to get the ISOweek and the start and end date of each every week in the whole year using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I want to get the complete ISOweek of a year from january 1 up to the 52nd week of the year.

and i want to get the startdate and enddate each every week.

I have my script here but I don't get the output that I want

**Script:**

```
Declare @starttime datetime
Declare @endtime datetime
Set @starttime = '2015-01-01 10:50:29.293'
Set @endtime = '2015-12-31 10:50:29.293'

declare @time datetime
while @endtime > @starttime
begin

print DATEPART(Week,@starttime)
print @starttime
set @time = DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime)
 If @time<@endtime
Begin

    print @time
    print DATEPART(Week,@time)

    set @starttime = DATEADD(DAY, 1,@time) 
End
Else
begin
    print @endtime
    print DATEPART(Week,@endtime)
     set @endtime = @starttime
End
end
```

**Output:**

```
1 --> this is the week of the @Starttime
Jan  1 2015 10:50AM -->@starttime
Jan  7 2015 10:50AM -->@endtime
2 --> this is the week of the endtime
```

...............

```
51
Dec 17 2015 10:50AM
Dec 23 2015 10:50AM
52
52
Dec 24 2015 10:50AM
Dec 30 2015 10:50AM
53
```

up to the end of the year.

**I want my output to be like this**

***Sample:***

```
1 --> this is the week of the @Starttime
Jan  1 2015 10:50AM -->@starttime
Jan  3 2015 10:50AM -->@endtime
1 --> this is the week of the @endtime
```

I want my starttime to be the firstdate of my week and my endtime to be the lastdate of the week until the year ends.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `DATEPART` with `WEEKDAY` to get day of the week and then use a  recursive CTE to get subsequent weeks. Something like this

```
DECLARE @dtstart DATETIME= '20150101'
DECLARE @dtend DATETIME= '20151231'

;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 1 as WeekNo, @dtstart weekstart,DATEADD(d,6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dtstart),@dtstart) weekend
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE.WeekNo + 1 as WeekNo, DATEADD(d,1,CTE.weekend),CASE WHEN  DATEADD(d,7,CTE.weekend) < @dtend THEN DATEADD(d,7,CTE.weekend) ELSE @dtend END
FROM CTE WHERE DATEADD(d,1,CTE.weekend) < @dtend
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```